# need help displaying mysql table in java console

Tags: java, mysql, console-application, crud

I am making a console app for this company to show what i have learned through a 5 week course i took. It is a console app that uses the crud operations with the MySQL database. It is a basic video game storage.

I got two layers. presentation and logic. My problem is I can't seem to get my view method to work. first it was only viewing one row from my table, then I added a for loop and it now displays nothing.

Here is my presentation layer:

```
public static void ViewAll() {

    List<Games> gamelist = new ArrayList<Games>();
    Logic aref = new Logic();
    aref.ViewAllGames();
    for(Games g : gamelist){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Game Id:   " + g.getGameId());
        System.out.println("Title:     " + g.getTitle());
        System.out.println("Rating:    " + g.getRating());
        System.out.println("Platform:  "+ g.getPlatform());
        System.out.println("Developer: "+ g.getDeveloper());
    }
}
```

Here is my logic layer:

```
public static List<Games> ViewAllGames() {
    List<Games> game = new ArrayList<Games>();
    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM games");
        while(rs.next()){
            Games g = new Games();
            for(Games gamelist : game){
                g.setGameId(rs.getInt("GameId"));
                g.setTitle(rs.getString("Title"));
                g.setRating(rs.getString("Rating"));
                g.setPlatform(rs.getString("Platform"));
                g.setDeveloper(rs.getString("Developer"));
                game.add(g);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return game;

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

---

EDIT: So I got it to print multiple rows just now it prints the last row over.
Here is the results:

Game Id:   10
Title:     Goldeneye 007
Rating:    M
Platform:  Nintendo 64
Developer: RockStar

Game Id:   10
Title:     Goldeneye 007
Rating:    M
Platform:  Nintendo 64
Developer: RockStar

Game Id:   10
Title:     Goldeneye 007
Rating:    M
Platform:  Nintendo 64
Developer: RockStar

Game Id:   10
Title:     Goldeneye 007
Rating:    M
Platform:  Nintendo 64
Developer: RockStar

Game Id:   10
Title:     Goldeneye 007
Rating:    M
Platform:  Nintendo 64
Developer: RockStar

Comment: Is that your latest code above?  You should remove the `for` loop in `ViewAllGames()` as I suggested; it doesn't make sense there and could be causing the problems you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

`aref.ViewAllGames()` returns the list of games, but you aren't doing anything with it.  The `for` loop, therefore, is looping over an empty list.  Try this:

```
public static void ViewAll() {

    Logic aref = new Logic();
    List<Games> gamelist = aref.ViewAllGames();
    for(Games g : gamelist){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Game Id:   " + g.getGameId());
        System.out.println("Title:     " + g.getTitle());
        System.out.println("Rating:    " + g.getRating());
        System.out.println("Platform:  "+ g.getPlatform());
        System.out.println("Developer: "+ g.getDeveloper());
    }
}
```

In response to your edit:

The `for` loop in `ViewAllGames()` doesn't belong there.  You should just iterate over the resultset, which you're doing, but simply add a new game to the list on each iteration:

```
while(rs.next()){
    Games g = new Games();
    g.setGameId(rs.getInt("GameId"));
    g.setTitle(rs.getString("Title"));
    g.setRating(rs.getString("Rating"));
    g.setPlatform(rs.getString("Platform"));
    g.setDeveloper(rs.getString("Developer"));
    game.add(g);
}
```

Comment: I used it and now its printing the three rows i have but instead of showing the three different games its all just madden nfl 2010

Comment: I recommend debugging through ViewAllGames(). I'm not sure you need that for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Solved It! Turns out I made GameId, Title, Rating, Platform, and Developer all static instead of public. sorry if I wasted anyones time! :)